# Outlook 2007 Search Folder to capture all email related to a domain

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2007, search-folder

I would like to generate a series of search folders in Outlook 2007, so that I can quickly view all emails related to a specific email domain.

Using the query builder, I've created criteria for

```
OR
+- To contains: example.com
+- From contains: example.com
```

The 'To' part works, as it finds all the emails that I've sent, but the from part doesn't.

If I replace the From clause to include the full name of a person at the domain e.g. Fred Bloggs (fred@example.com) as follows:

```
OR
+- To contains: example.com
+- From contains: Fred Bloggs
```

Then this works as expected, but I don't want to have to list all the possible people that might email from the example.com domain.

There must be an easy way of doing this, that I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've figured it out, (although I'm not sure why 'From:' doesn't appear to include the senders email address).

The way to achieve this is to simply select 'Mail from and to specific people', rather than going into the query builder.